# Rails Admin errors out when where condition assoicated with a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-admin, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many association between my Activity model and Photo Model.

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos, -> { where(photos: { deleted: false })}
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
end
```

I have installed rails_admin for creating the admin pages for these models.

However when I try to access the 'admin/activity/new' page I get an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

on the line where the has_and_belongs_to_many association is defined for photos.

When I remove the where condition from the association I am able to access the 'admin/activity/new'.

Is there any problem with where conditions on the has_and_belongs_to_many association with rails_admin or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ? Im also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `->` you can use  `Proc.new`

e.g.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :photos, Proc.new { where(photos: { deleted: false })}
```

This worked for me

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Seems to be an issue specifically with `has_and_belongs_to_many`